# How to read Enumeration values via. pyads

Tags: python, twincat, twincat-ads

I'm recently using the package pyads to connect to Beckhoff TwinCAT3. The reading and writing methods work smoothly. (BTW: TwinCAT3 works fine)

But some error occurs when I try to write a value into an enumeration in TwinCAT3.

I'm using the easiest code to test:

```
eCtrlMode = plc.write_by_name("GVL_Tset.stTest.eCtrlMode", 1)
```

eCtrlMode is the instance of an enumeration "E_CtrlMode".
The enumeration "E_CtrlMode in" TwinCAT3 as following:

```
TYPE E_CtrlMode:
(
    Off := 0,
    Auto := 1,
    Reset := 10,
    Manual := 20
);
END_TYPE
```

Error returns:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Any help, direct or recommended reading would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, first time being here, the title was false and I can not change it. the question is how to write not how to read. Thanks :)

Comment: It's been solved :)
a PLCTYPE property should be added

Comment: Can you add your solution as answer covering what you did to solve and give a quick an example if possible? Just so that if anyone else comes looking they can follow through.

Answer (score 3):

Solution right now:
An enumeration in this case is no other than a group of INT values. By using the write_by_name function, the pyads.PLCTYPE_INT property should always be added, otherwise it won't work:

```
eCtrlMode = plc.write_by_name("GVL_Tset.stTest.eCtrlMode", 1, pyads.PLCTYPE_INT)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question from the question title:
"How to read Enumeration values via. pyads"

If anyone get here for the **reading** of an enum this should work

```
eCtrlMode = plc.read_by_name("GVL_Tset.stTest.eCtrlMode", pyads.PLCTYPE_INT)
```